Using H264 JM Reference, how to get the intra-frame prediction mode (for 8x8 and 4x4 blocks) from the trace xml
I want to recover (using Python) the image for i frame, for research purposes.
The traces I got from JM Reference using ./jm_16.1/bin/ldecod.exe contains the following:
For 16x16, the <TypeString> actually contains the prediction mode like I_16x16_2_1_0. but for 8x8 and 4x4 they do not contain the prediction mode.
                <MacroBlock num="40">
                    <Position>
                        <X>640</X>
                        <Y>0</Y>
                    </Position>
                    <QP_Y>26</QP_Y>
                    <Type>0</Type>
                    <TypeString>**I_4x4**</TypeString>
                    <PredModeString>BLOCK_TYPE_I</PredModeString>
                    <SkipFlag>0</SkipFlag>
                    <Coeffs>
                        <Plane type="0">
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                        </Plane>
                        <Plane type="1">
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,-160,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>-160,0,0,0,-320,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                        </Plane>
                        <Plane type="2">
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>160,0,0,0,160,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                            <Row>0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0</Row>
                        </Plane>
                    </Coeffs>
                </MacroBlock>


GPT said it might be different for sub blocks in a macroblock, also in JM Reference, I see the sub macroblock information. But in my case, the traces do not have any information about this.
In the case that the trace contains the intra-frame prediction mode information like I_16x16_2_2_1, the motion prediction can better recover the luma frame.
An example is below (sorry, I use JSON in this trace example, converted from xml),
import json
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import idct
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the quantization scale (QP) values
DEFAULT_4x4_QUANT_MATRIX = np.array([
    [16, 11, 10, 16],
    [12, 12, 14, 19],
    [14, 13, 16, 24],
    [14, 17, 22, 29]
], dtype=np.uint16)

# Function to apply IDCT to a 16x16 block by processing 4x4 sub-blocks
def apply_idct_16x16(block):
    result = np.zeros((16, 16))
    for i in range(0, 16, 4):
        for j in range(0, 16, 4):
            sub_block = block[i:i+4, j:j+4]
            result[i:i+4, j:j+4] = idct(idct(sub_block, axis=0, norm='ortho'), axis=1, norm='ortho')
    return result

# Function to inverse quantize a block
def inverse_quantize(block, q_scale):
    quant_matrix = np.full(block.shape, q_scale, dtype=np.float64)

    # quant_matrix = np.tile(DEFAULT_4x4_QUANT_MATRIX, (4, 4))
    return block * quant_matrix

QP_SCALE_CR = {
    0: [13107, 5243, 8066],
    1: [11916, 4660, 7490],
    2: [10082, 4194, 6554],
    3: [9362, 3647, 5825],
    4: [8192, 3355, 5243],
    5: [7282, 2893, 4559]
}

def get_q_scale(qp):
    q_bits = 15 + (qp // 6)
    return QP_SCALE_CR[qp % 6][0] >> (q_bits - 15)

# Load the JSON data
with open('json_traces/meerkat_CIF_0_trace.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

frame_width, frame_height = 352, 192

# Initialize full-frame residue arrays for Y, Cb, and Cr
residue_Y = np.zeros((frame_height, frame_width))

def predict_block(mb_x, mb_y, mode, block_size, residue):
    predicted_block = np.zeros((block_size, block_size))
    
    if mode == '0':
        # Mode 0: Vertical Prediction
        for col in range(block_size):
            predicted_block[:, col] = residue[mb_y - 1, mb_x + col] if mb_y > 0 else 0
    elif mode == '1':
        # Mode 1: Horizontal Prediction
        for row in range(block_size):
            predicted_block[row, :] = residue[mb_y + row, mb_x - 1] if mb_x > 0 else 0
    elif mode == '2':
        # Mode 2: DC Prediction
        top_mean = np.mean(residue[mb_y - 1, mb_x:mb_x + block_size]) if mb_y > 0 else 0
        left_mean = np.mean(residue[mb_y:mb_y + block_size, mb_x - 1]) if mb_x > 0 else 0
        dc_value = (top_mean + left_mean) / 2
        predicted_block.fill(dc_value)
    elif mode == '3':
        # Mode 3: Diagonal Down-Left Prediction
        for i in range(block_size):
            for j in range(block_size):
                if mb_y - 1 + i < 0 or mb_x + 1 + j >= residue.shape[1]:
                    predicted_block[i, j] = 0
                else:
                    predicted_block[i, j] = residue[mb_y - 1 + i, mb_x + 1 + j]

    return predicted_block

for i, mb in enumerate(data['SubPicture']['Slice']['MacroBlock']):
    print(i)
    mb_x = int(mb['Position']['X'])
    mb_y = int(mb['Position']['Y'])
    qp_y = int(mb['QP_Y'])
    luma_mode = mb['TypeString'].split("_")[2]
    
    q_scale = get_q_scale(qp_y)

    coeffs_Y = np.array([int(num) for row in mb['Coeffs']['Plane'][0]['Row'] for num in row.split(',')]).reshape(16, 16)
    
    # Inverse quantization
    block_Y = inverse_quantize(coeffs_Y, q_scale)

    # IDCT
    residue_block_Y = apply_idct_16x16(block_Y)

    # Intra-frame prediction
    predicted_Y = predict_block(mb_x, mb_y, luma_mode, 16, residue_Y)
    
    # Add the predicted block to the de-quantized block to get the residual values
    predicted_Y += residue_block_Y

    
    # Place in the full-frame residue array
    residue_Y[mb_y:mb_y+16, mb_x:mb_x+16] = predicted_Y

# Normalize the residue values to the range 0-255 for visualization
residue_Y_normalized = residue_Y - np.min(residue_Y)
residue_Y_normalized = residue_Y_normalized / np.max(residue_Y_normalized) * 255
residue_Y_normalized = residue_Y_normalized.astype(np.uint8)

# Plot the normalized residue
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
plt.imshow(residue_Y_normalized, cmap='gray', interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('Residue Y Visualization')
plt.show()


without intra-frame prediction, the recovered luma results show like below,

with the prediction and I got luma image like below,


(1) What is an i-frame in this question? Do you mean an IDR keyframe (intra with header byte 0x65) or you mean a literal I frame (inter with header byte 0x41, and yes that same byte value is used to signal even P and B frames)? (2) If you are talking about IDR, then there should not be any prediction data. It resets everything to zero. If I remember correctly, It is only the I/P/B frames that hold such data. Double check your bytes header. (3) Give the decoder correct input for getting the expected results. An MB of one color fill, will not have 4x4 data

I don't think anyone ever considers "I"-frames to mean "inter". the "I" literally stands for "intra". any temporal prediction is done by P and B slices. the major diff between IDR ("Instantaneous Decoder Refresh") and "mere" I-frames is that IDR blocks/clears existing reference frames so they are worthless for predictions, so following P/B frames won't reach further back than the IDR. both IDR and I decode using no reference frames, but frames following an I-frame may refer to frames before it. not so with IDR.

@ChristophRackwitz Sounds like an urban myth you read on some random forum post....  "I frames are intra (not "inter"), i.e. produce a complete picture on their own" Wow, you must have really nice I frames. The one's I dealt with use slice groups and/or macroblocks from previous and future frames. It was the nightmare point I tried to warn about in the first paragraph of this Question, but that rant likely needs some visual examples to make sense. Might update one day...

@ChristophRackwitz Oh your comment has changed... No worries it's this new computer. Yeah you'd think I stands for Intra but not with some H.264 I-frames I've seen. Unless encoders of h.264 versus x264 are doing different things. My encoders are only ever Chrome (WebCodecs API) and FFmpeg commandline. I have seen non-Intra I frames. Especially when using Baseline profile.

@VC.One I am really new to this area. In this case, I force every frame to a video (I would guess it is intra I frame and an IDR frame, from JM reference, I cannot see the header byte) and it should have no motion compensation.
I checked the P and B frames (others videos, from JM reference, I can see the motion vectors, but not this one)

@VC.One I am dealing with intra-frame decoding. The macroblock should be of size16x16. I have used IDCT (4x4 block size) and inverse quantization to decode the luma residues. But it falls the next step to recover the luma image from the residues.

@VC.One I think it would need the intra-frame prediction mode like vertical, horizontal, DC, ... But from the JM reference, only the 16x16 block contains prediction mode while 8x8 and 4x4 does not. I_16x16_2_2_1 according to GPT may mean 2=DC mode for luma, and 2=DC mode for chroma, not sure about the meaning of the last 1.
This is another place that I got quite confusing, in H264, it seems like only 9 mode for 4x4, and 4 mode for 16x16, there is no 8x8. So it does not make sense to me.

@YuhangYe "I have used IDCT (4x4 block size)" is it possible that such MB itself is using an MB_mode_0 config like as shown by the first (top left) diagram? The I frame doesn't usually have motion vectors (also like IDR) since the P/B are the actual "movement" frames of areas (luma and chroma) from the last nearest keyframe. Can you provide a download link for the bytes of the frame? Let me know if you can do it and I'll let you know what to provide...

@VC.One
Many thanks, I uploaded the files (the video only contains an image, originate from in the REDS dataset) to the git, the link https://github.com/yyhtbs-yye/h264_analysis, it contains 264 container, the original mp4, and the xml trace (I have not changed it to json file). I received from JM reference ldecod.exe file.

@YuhangYe Thanks for uploading. The H264 file you provided is of an IDR keyframe. What do you need from that keyframe? Is it that you want to get the Luma channel? and just to clarify.: your question here is that your code gets a bad picture result and so how to fix such code? If yes, show the luma you got from the bus image (not meerkat image). I will try to re-create your code in Javascript but it will take a few days to Answer properly. I can advise in the comments anytime.

@VC.One, Sorry for the late : P, I read the JM reference trace code (even with the most detailed trace logging setting, it seems like for I frame they do not provide block-level prediction mode (4x4, 8x8). But the problem is that for 4x4 block and 8x8 block, the residue's idct output is of poor quality, have my code and video seqs uploaded to https://github.com/yyhtbs-yye/h264_decode/tree/main.
